# R detect consecutive month-day

Tags: r

I have a  dataframe  with one column having all the date info. The new dataframe was created  by  extracting  month-day  format so later I could do a group_by.

```
   df1=seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'),as.Date('2011-01-05'),by = 1)
   df2=seq(as.Date('2010-12-28'),as.Date('2010-12-31'),by = 1)
   df3=seq(as.Date('2011-01-16'),as.Date('2011-01-18'),by = 1)
   df=c(df1,df2,df3)
   s = format(df,"%m-%d")
```

s is the new dataframe and is character. s looks like this:

```
  [1] "01-01" "01-02" "01-03" "01-04" "01-05" "12-28" "12-29"
  [8] "12-30" "12-31" "01-16" "01-17" "01-18"
```

How could I detect from "12-28" to "01-05"  is consecutive.

If it is in Date format I could use diff to  detect, but with character, any suggestion?

Comment: why not using `diff(df)` ?

Comment: I have massive data and  across many years.  but  consecutive  month-day  is more important.